# How do I fix this error "React Native version mismatch Javascript 0.62.1 Native version 0.61.4"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am not able to run my react native project in the expo app since I'm getting the following error:

"console.error: React Native version mismatch.

Javascript version: 0.62.1
Native version: 0.61.4

Make sure that you have rebuilt the native code. If the problem persists ty clearing the Watchman and packager caches with 'watchman watch-del-all && react-native start --reset cache'."

This error message isn't helpful to me at all. Does this mean that I have to update my simulator? I don't think this is a suitable solution. How can I build an app that can be run on my simulator (Pixel 2 API 29)

Comment: So, what happens when you try the suggested solution?

Comment: It actually worked out fine.